# Add aliases for a watch command having pipe

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu-16.04

I want to have an alias named `fdbtop` for the below command

```
watch -tc 'fdbcli --exec "status json" | python /home/ubuntu/build-target/healthservice/fdbtop.py'
```

I tried adding the below line in `.bash_aliases`

```
alias 'fdbtop=watch -tc \''fdbcli --exec "status json" | python /home/ubuntu/build-target/healthservice/fdbtop.py\'''
```

But it gave me the below error

```
ubuntu@vrni-platform:~$ fdbtop
python: can't open file '/home/ubuntu/build-target/healthservice/fdbtop.py ': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
                                                                                                                 ubuntu@vrni-platform:~$
```

The file is present

```
ubuntu@vrni-platform:~$ ls /home/ubuntu/build-target/healthservice/fdbtop.py
/home/ubuntu/build-target/healthservice/fdbtop.py
```

Can someone let me know how to do this ?

OS Version - Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Use a shell function instead of alias

Comment: Within a single quoted string, a single quote is `'\''`. Check your string syntax.

Comment: @AlexP Can you post this as an answer ? I understood what you meant `alias 'fdbtop=watch -tc '\''fdbcli --exec "status json" | python /home/ubuntu/build-target/healthservice/fdbtop.py'\'''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alias fdbtop='watch -tc '\''fdbcli --exec "status json" | python /home/ubuntu/build-target/healthservice/fdbtop.py'\'
```

Within a string in single quotes no character is special. To insert a single quote in a string in single quotes you must use `'\''`. (The first `'` terminates the string, `\'` adds a single quote, the last `'` opens the string again.)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by anubhava, this is more suited to a function.  You can add this similarly to adding an alias (usually in your .bashrc file though you can source a function specific file if you'd rather).

```
function fdbtop() { 
    watch -tc 'fdbcli --exec "status json" | python /home/ubuntu/build-target/healthservice/fdbtop.py' 
}
```

Comment: Note that `function funcname {` is legacy (pre-POSIX) ksh syntax, whereas `funcname() {` is the POSIX-compliant function declaration. Combining the two gets you a result compatible with neither POSIX nor legacy ksh; see discussion at https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Yeah.  I know.  Thanks, CD.